# Radio Drama Evaluation

Tags: radio, drama, evaluation

Hey guys,

I am needing one of you to evaluate my first effort of a radio drama I produced for my honours project.  All it will require is for you to listen to it, take notes during listening, and then filling out a questionnaire for a further 15 minutes.  It is 60 minutes long, which I know is a long time for some of you busy folk, but I am really interested in building a career in radio dramas and I would like someone with experience help me evaluate my work.

Let me know if you're willing to help

Thanks

Richard Laing

Answer (score 1):

A link to your work could raise some interest ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry!

http://soundcloud.com/richardlaing/man-with-travel-hairdryer

I'm a bit of a tube sometimes!

Thanks

Comment: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6231633_0789714_278553

Hopefully the link above works, it's the evaluation questionnaire. It would be great if you fill it out after listening and email me at richardlaing2311@gmail.com with your answers.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

link it up and I'll give it a listen

Comment: http://soundcloud.com/richardlaing/man-with-travel-hairdryer

There you go.  Thanks very much!

Comment: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6231633_0789714_278553

Hopefully the link above works, it's the evaluation questionnaire. It would be great if you fill it out after listening and email me at richardlaing2311@gmail.com with your answers.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hey Richard,

I'm a big fan of Radio Documentary and drama. I'd be glad to help

Kurt

Comment: http://soundcloud.com/richardlaing/man-with-travel-hairdryer

I hope you like it.  It's not perfect; the main problem was with the dialogue recordings.  I was a bit clumsy during recording and I tried my best to recover it using Expander/Gate in Pro Tools (maybe a bit too much in some areas!).  I'll post up a link to the questionnaire soon.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6231633_0789714_278553

Hopefully the link above works, it's the evaluation questionnaire. It would be great if you fill it out after listening and email me at richardlaing2311@gmail.com with your answers.  Thanks again!